# ImageView SharedElement Resized Before Transition

Tags: android, kotlin, imageview, shared-element-transition

I have a `MainActivity` holding 2 fragments - `MainFragment` and `SlideshowFragment`. Both fragments are using `ViewPager` with `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` to hold `childFragments`.

When an `ImageView` in `ChildFragmentA` of `MainFragment` is clicked, it is to expand and fill the `PhotoView` in `ChildFragmentB` of `SlideshowFragment`. The `ImageView` is held in a `RecyclerView`.

I've referred to the Android Official Guide [here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/02/continuous-shared-element-transitions.html), looked that its GitHub code and had made the required change to make sure the transition names and callback are properly set.

However, `ImageView` is using `centerCrop` in xml, while `PhotoView` is using `fitCenter`. The result is that before the transition happen, the image will expand first, which is very unpleasant. Gif [here](https://i.imgur.com/lJQPvd0.gif) (irrelevant, but appreciate if someone can let me know how to embed gif).

Below are some of the relevant codes.

### Loading of image into view with Glide

```
GlideApp.with(getActivityContext())
    .load(filePath)
    .dontTransform()    // I found some posts that say this should be set
    .listener(object : RequestListener<Drawable> {
        override fun onLoadFailed(e: GlideException?, model: Any?, target: Target<Drawable>?,
                                  isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
            startPostponedEnterTransition()
            return false
        }

        override fun onResourceReady(resource: Drawable?, model: Any?, target: Target<Drawable>?,
                                     dataSource: DataSource?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
            startPostponedEnterTransition()
            return false
        }
    })
    .into(imageView)
```

### Preparation of transition in SlideshowFragment

```
private fun prepareSharedElementTransition() {
    val transition = TransitionInflater.from(getActivityContext())
            .inflateTransition(R.transition.image_shared_element_transition)
    transition.duration = 1000
    sharedElementEnterTransition = transition
    sharedElementReturnTransition = transition    // it wasn't working, so I tried adding this line too
    setEnterSharedElementCallback(
            object : SharedElementCallback() {
                override fun onMapSharedElements(names: List<String>, sharedElements: MutableMap<String, View>) {
                    // mapping stuff here done correctly
                }
            })
}
```

### XML

```
<!-- In ChildFragmentA -->
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/thumbnailLayout_thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

<!-- In ChildFragmentB -->
<com.github.chrisbanes.photoview.PhotoView
    android:id="@+id/childFragmentB_photoView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

<!-- In image_shared_element_transition.xml -->
<transitionSet xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"
    android:transitionOrdering="together">
    <changeBounds/>
    <changeClipBounds/>
    <changeTransform/>
</transitionSet>
```

Really appreciate any help as I have spent 2 days on this.

Comment: @pskink, is there any resource that you can point me to or perhaps some code to show? Most of the sites that I found are just re-telling the story of what I found on Android Official Guide.

Comment: Do we have an easier method using xml?

Comment: @pskink, well... tried that and was not working. There's no issue with the viewtype, but the scale type I think.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Did you solve this issue ?

Comment: @PaulSouteyrat, unfortunately no. In the end, I used Activity to Activity transition: Fragment A in Activity A --> Fragment B in Activity B. That then worked properly. I have open-sourced my app at https://github.com/tingyik90/Pholder. You can get try my app at https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dokidevs.pholder.

Comment: There are a lot of comments within the code. You should look into `startSlideshow()` method of `GalleryBaseActivity` and follow the method calls.